# No Google Play Store on Huawei devices, nor within Huawei HiApp store

Tags: google-play-store, huawei

I recently got a Huawei P10, but there is only Huawei HiApp store, not Google Play Store. I want to download the Google Play Store, but I cannot find it in the HiApp store.

How can I install Google Play Store on this Huawei device?

Answer (score 1):

Huawei devices (and other smartphone brands) whose default ROM originates from China, have a certain geo-restriction that prevents accessing most Google apps and services and most (if not all) don't ship with Google Playstore pre-installed.

Instead the OEM based store called HiApp, is the default app store, with which you can download more apps. Fortunately the process of installing Google Play store is not a big hassle at all if you reside outside China (otherwise you might need to install a VPN beforehand).

Using the HiApp store app, **you can simply search and install Google Play store in a few taps** as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

You coud also you the web version of app store here: http://appstore.huawei.com

alternatively you get still get the .apk file on [apkmirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/) and side-load it normally.

PS *I have a Huawei tablet with China ROM, that did not have Google playstore preinstalled and I simply used the above process, and it works well  alongside **microG***.

Answer (score -1):

The Google Play app should already be installed on your phone. Look in your App drawer.